# Can you give some verses that challenge people to prove quran is false.?

Tags: quran, verses

Quran challenge people to prove quran is false and to prove its not from Allah. Can can anyone. Provide some verse that has this challenge.

Expect the verse to write something like quran(chapter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think those verses you are looking for that, Allah challenges People**

**Below Three verses**

Say, "If mankind and the jinn gathered in order to produce the like of this Qur'an, they could not produce the like of it, even if they were to each other assistants."

[[17] Al-Isra' : 88](https://qurano.com/en/17-al-isra/verse-88/)

Or do they say, "He invented it"? Say, "Then bring ten surahs like it that have been invented and call upon [for assistance] whomever you can besides Allah, if you should be truthful."

[Surah Hud Verse 13](https://qurano.com/en/11-hud/verse-13/)

And if you are in doubt about what We have sent down upon Our Servant [Muhammad], then produce a surah the like thereof and call upon your witnesses other than Allah, if you should be truthful.

[Surah Al-Baqara Verse 23](https://qurano.com/en/2-al-baqara/verse-23/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer